# How to properly structure Java's ternary operator compared to if statements?

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I have a simple question about two versions of the same code, one using the ternary operator and one using if statements, and why they differ in their answer.

Background information on the problem. I'm trying to easily sort an array of integers and get the range of the array as well (max & min)

array given: [6, 2, 3, 8]

If statement version:

```
public int range(int[] num_list) {
    int[] min_max = new int[2];
    for (int i : statues) {
         if (min_max[0] == 0) {
            min_max[0] = i;
        } else {
            if (i < min_max[0]) min_max[0] = i;
        }
         if (min_max[1] == 0) {
            min_max[1] = i;
        } else {
            if (i > min_max[1]) min_max[1] = i;
        }
  System.out.println(String.valueOf(min_max[0] + " | " + min_max[1]));
    }
}
```

Console log:

```
6 | 6
2 | 6
2 | 6
2 | 8
```

---

Ternary operator version:

```
public int range(int[] num_list) {
    int[] min_max = new int[2];
    for (int i : statues) {
        min_max[0] = min_max[0] == 0 ? i 
               : (min_max[0] = i < min_max[0] ? i : i);
        min_max[1] = min_max[1] == 0 ? i 
               : (min_max[1] = i > min_max[1] ? i : i);
  System.out.println(String.valueOf(min_max[0] + " | " + min_max[1]));
    }
}
```

Console log:

```
6 | 6
2 | 2
3 | 3
8 | 8
```

**Why is the ternary operator version incorrect? To my knowledge, it should be a ternary-replica of the if statement version?**

Comment: What is that second part of the ternary expression `(min_max[0] = i < min_max[0] ? i : i)` even supposed to do? An assignment in the condition (???), and both case values are identical.

Comment: Also the logic of your if-else is very strange. If A do this else if B also do this. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: I tried to make it replicate what the if statement version is doing - As in 'if min is 0, set it to 'i', else, if i is smaller than min, set min to i"

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen this is actually a good point - What is the preferred structure for an if statement like that? Would it use an if statement? I went for 'If A, do this, otherwise check if this to set A to this instead of this other thing'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire thing can be rewritten using `if` conditions as:

```
public int range(int[] num_list) {
    int[] min_max = new int[2];
    for (int i : statues) {
        if (min_max[0] == 0 || i < min_max[0]) {
            min_max[0] = i;
        }

        if (min_max[1] == 0 || i > min_max[1]) {
            min_max[1] = i;
        }

        System.out.println(String.valueOf(min_max[0] + " | " + min_max[1]));
    }
}
```

If you *really* want to use ternary expressions:

```
public int range(int[] num_list) {
    int[] min_max = new int[2];
    for (int i : statues) {
        min_max[0] = (min_max[0] == 0 || i < min_max[0]) ? i : min_max[0];
        min_max[1] = (min_max[1] == 0 || i > min_max[1]) ? i : min_max[1];

        System.out.println(String.valueOf(min_max[0] + " | " + min_max[1]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes. This:

```
    if (min_max[0] == 0) {
        min_max[0] = i;
    } else {
        if (i < min_max[0]) min_max[0] = i;
    }
```

is equivalent to this:

```
    min_max[0] = min_max[0] == 0 ? i :
        (i < min_max[0] ? i : min_max[0]);
```

Note, in the ternary operator "else" has to be always there. So you need to put something in it - in this case assigning the old value is analogous to doing nothing.

Similarly story for the second if statement.

Comment: Just take it one step further: `if a then x else if b then x` is the same as `if a or b then x`. You don't need a nested ternary expression.